# NUnit: is it possible to reference classes from my application?

Tags: c#, unit-testing, testing, nunit, 64-bit

I recently ran into a brick wall with Visual Studio 2008's testing framework: [testing 64 bit dlls is not possible with VS 2008](http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/forums/en-US/vststest/thread/7a693fc1-71ba-4ca7-b706-7e339fc9e7b5/). I have a project that compiles to x64 only and I need to create some unit tests for the project and I can't use the VS2008 testing framework to do it.

Subsequently, I downloaded the latest NUnit framework (which as far as I understand supports x64 testing), but now I'm trying to duplicate the same behavior that Visual Studio had with its testing framework. Namely, I would like to instantiate classes within the text fixture that are defined in my project.

Here is an example:

- I have a project (call it MyProject) that compiles to an executable: MyProject.exe
- There is a class within MyProject that's called `MyClass`.
- I have a separate project for my tests, called MyProjectTest, and it compiles to a dll (so I can run it with NUnit).
- How can I instantiate `MyClass` inside MyProjectTest?

As far as I understand NUnit seems to be designed for testing DLLs not EXEs, so what do I have to do if I want to test classes within an EXE? Reflection? I assume that's how VS2008's testing framework gets access to the classes...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> How can I instantiate MyClass inside MyProjectTest?

The normal way to do this is for your MyProjectTest project to contain a reference to MyProject

But it seems most people don't like the idea of referencing an exe and hence would have MyClass defined in a third dll which is referenced by both the MyProject and MyProjectTest

> As far as I understand NUnit seems to be designed for testing DLLs not EXEs.

I must admit, all my tests are in dlls, but the default filespec for the Nunit Add assembly dialog box is *.dll and *.exe which would suggest otherwise.

Comment: frankly, I have no problem referencing an exe... I think I might just do that.

Comment: +1 Though it is technically possible to reference exes now, the traditional way was to create DLLs so that the main launcher exe and the test dll can both refer to the production code. It still 'feels' (subjective) like the right thing to me

Answer (score 4):

An executable and a DLL are nearly identical. There are some differences, but none that should serve as a hindrance to referencing an executable from your NUnit test project.

Comment: sounds like that's what I might do.